# Add enhancer to redux store after createStore()

Tags: redux

Is this possible?

I'm using `redux` store in an IoC environment and want to add middleware to the store after it is created.

e.g.:

```
class MyApp {
  store = createStore(...);
}

let app = new MyApp();

// later on
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
app.store.addEnhancer(thunk);
```

Comment: I would be interested in why this is necessary? Adding middleware later on could make the store and updates less predictable. What's your use case?

Comment: This is done for a different approach. `redux` is top-down, the application determine which module it would use. What I am working on is IoC / plugin based, thus the whole logic is decentralized. That's why I need to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have created a function to do this. If `redux` think this is valuable, I can do a PR.

This is code that tailored to my module. The actual one add to PR will look a bit different.

```
addMiddleware(middleware: Middleware) {
  const middlewareAPI: MiddlewareAPI<any> = {
    getState: this.getState,
    dispatch: (action) => this.dispatch(action)
  };

  this.dispatch = compose(middleware(middlewareAPI))(this.dispatch);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I was able to use the code from above from unional but I needed to change it slightly to get it working with 2018 redux.

```
constructor(myMiddleware: myMiddleware) {
           this.addMiddleware(myMiddleware)
        }

addMiddleware(middleware: Middleware) {

  this.redux.dispatch = compose(applyMiddleware(middleware))(this.redux.dispatch);

 }
```